# iptables doesn't add NAT rule

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I'm triying to forward a port from host to lxc guest:
`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.0.3.31:3000`

on lxc guest is running a nodejs server serving a website
 I cannot see the added rule here:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN
```

but I don't receive any errors by calling iptables -t nat...
and obviously the redirection doesn't work

I really have no idea on how to do it.
can some one help me?
thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add port forwarding on the host machine to LXC container:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to XX.XX.XX.XX:80
```

To view list iptables rules use:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -L
```

Should give you an output like this:

[image]

If you still don't see your Node.js app, try curl to see if it actually responding properly.

```
curl http://10.0.3.31:3000
```

Also don't forget to persist your port forwarding rules, you can further read in my blog post: https://drifts.io/how-to-setup-http-https-ssh-port-forwarding-to-lxc-container/